# Capturing Audio from system-audio or browser via HTML5

Tags: html, audio, stream, capture

I wonder if it's possible to capture browser-audio or even system-audio via html5 and then sending to a server? i searched already 2 years ago for a solution but maybe now it's possible. :) i think the main problem is the internal routing in the OS right?

Answer (score 0):

iv'e found a tutorial for this kind of things - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: thx for answer, but that's problem. in all tutorials you just can select mic or video as the source, but not the system input oder "browser input". like i want to capture for example a radio stream from a browser tab. so the source must be the system audio or the browser....or did i missed something?